# Customize the border of a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I want to set the border of textfield like in the shown image. 
I have used following code but it's giving me the full border:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.textfield.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(Float(1.0))
    self.textfield.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(Float(5.0))

}
```

Comment: I can help you with just bottom border, if you want

Comment: You can add your textfield in a uiview & in uiview you draw this bottom line or add uiimageview with image is this bottom line

Answer (score 0):

You can use background images for custom border. Use a image with your border so you will get desired bordered textField.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom UITextField class and inside its `awakeFromNib` you can add that line image as its subview. If that would be a straight line , i will recommend you to add a layer to your textField.